# rails submit check box with matching select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, erb

I have a form that is displaying dates and times like so [image]

The code for it looks like this:

```
 <%= f.fields_for :availabilities do |ff| %>
<% ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"].each do |day| %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="ck-button">
          <label>
            <%= ff.check_box "day", {multiple: true, checked: @therapist.available_times.key?(day)}, day, false %>
            <span><%= day %></span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="answer">
          <%= ff.select "start_time", ["1 AM", "2 AM", "3 AM", "4 AM", "5 AM", "6 AM", "7 AM", "8 AM", "9 AM", "10 AM", "11 AM", "12 PM", "1 PM", "2 PM", "3 PM", "4 PM", "5 PM", "6 PM", "7 PM", "8 PM", "9 PM", "10 PM", "11 PM"], {:selected => (@therapist.available_times.key?(day) ? @therapist.available_times[day][:start] : '7' )} %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="answer">
          <%= ff.select "end_time", ["1 AM", "2 AM", "3 AM", "4 AM", "5 AM", "6 AM", "7 AM", "8 AM", "9 AM", "10 AM", "11 AM", "12 PM", "1 PM", "2 PM", "3 PM", "4 PM", "5 PM", "6 PM", "7 PM", "8 PM", "9 PM", "10 PM", "11 PM"], {:selected => (@therapist.available_times.key?(day) ? @therapist.available_times[day][:end] : '17' )} %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

When I submit this however, the data sent to my controller looks like this:

```
"availabilities"=>{"start_time"=>"1 AM", "end_time"=>"1 AM", "day"=>["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]}
```

What I really want is to get:

```
"availabilities"=>[{"start_time"=> "1 AM", "end_time"=>"1 AM", "day" => "Monday"},{"start_time"=> ...},...]
```

only for the days that are selected.

From the controller side, I have the permit looking as:

```
:availabilities => [:day, :start_time, :end_time],
```

EDIT:
I changed the `multiple` to `false` and now my availabilities has the form I want but I only get the last checked, not an array of all the checked fields and their associated times

Answer (score 1):

You have to group the field names by something. try this:

First, use `each_with_index` to have some index to group them:

```
["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"].each_with_indexx do |day, idx|
```

Now you can write something like this:

```
<%= ff.check_box "availabilities[#{idx}][day]", .... %>
<%= ff.select "availabilitlies[#{idx}][start_time]", .... %>
<%= ff.select "availabilitlies[#{idx}][end_time]", .... %>
```

Params will be a little different, instead of an array of objects you'll have this:

```
availabilities => {'0' => {'day' => 'Sunday', "start_time" => .., "end_time" => ...}, '1' => {'day' => 'Monday', .... }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :availabilities do |ff| %>     
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="ck-button">
      <label>
      <% days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wen', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'] %>
      <% days.map do |day| %>          
      <%= ff.check_box :count,{multiple: false},day,nil %>
      <%= ff.label day %>
      <%end%>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="answer">
      <%= ff.select "start_time", ["1 AM", "2 AM", "3 AM", "4 AM", "5 AM", "6 AM", "7 AM", "8 AM", "9 AM", "10 AM", "11 AM", "12 PM", "1 PM", "2 PM", "3 PM", "4 PM", "5 PM", "6 PM", "7 PM", "8 PM", "9 PM", "10 PM", "11 PM"], {:selected => (@therapist.available_times.key?(day) ? @therapist.available_times[day][:start] : '7' )} %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="answer">
      <%= ff.select "end_time", ["1 AM", "2 AM", "3 AM", "4 AM", "5 AM", "6 AM", "7 AM", "8 AM", "9 AM", "10 AM", "11 AM", "12 PM", "1 PM", "2 PM", "3 PM", "4 PM", "5 PM", "6 PM", "7 PM", "8 PM", "9 PM", "10 PM", "11 PM"], {:selected => (@therapist.available_times.key?(day) ? @therapist.available_times[day][:end] : '17' )} %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>  <% end %>
```